# PyQt5 Radio Button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-datetime

In the code below, I am trying to record the field values ​​for the selected radio buttons. But after the first click and saving the data in variables, when you click another or the same radio button, the values ​​​​of the variables are not updated to the new ones.
Please help fix this!

```
import datetime
```

from datetime import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QButtonGroup

```
from TimeTable import Ui_MainWindow

class SheetsForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.EvereDate1.hide()
        self.EveryDate2.hide()
        self.WaWdate1.hide()
        self.WaWdate2.hide()
        self.OnceDate.hide()
        self.AddBottom.clicked.connect(self.Add)
        self.EvereDate1.setMinimumDate(QDate(2022, 9, 1))
        self.EveryDate2.setMinimumDate(QDate(2022, 9, 1))
        self.WaWdate1.setMinimumDate(QDate(2022, 9, 1))
        self.WaWdate2.setMinimumDate(QDate(2022, 9, 1))
        self.OnceDate.setMinimumDate(QDate(2022, 9, 1))
        self.group = QButtonGroup()
        self.group.addButton(self.EveryWeeks,1)
        self.group.addButton(self.WeekAfterWeek, 2)
        self.group.addButton(self.OnceTime, 3)
        self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.rbtn)
        self.date1 = ""
        self.date2 = ""
        self.date = ""
        file = open("test1.txt", "+w")
        file.write("Дата начала     Дата конца      Время начала        Время конца     Продолжительность       Имя преподавателя       Назаваание предмета\n")
        file.close()


def Add(self):
    paramTecher = self.TeachText.toPlainText()
    paramSubj = self.SubjText.toPlainText()
    self.timeStart = self.timeF.time().toPyTime()
    self.timeEnd = self.timeL.time().toPyTime()
    

    def td(self):
        str_ts = self.timeStart.strftime("%H %M")
        str_te = self.timeEnd.strftime("%H %M")
        s = [int(s) for s in str.split(str_ts) if s.isdigit()]
        e = [int(e) for e in str.split(str_te) if e.isdigit()]

        s_sec = 0
        e_sec = 0
        for i in s:
            s_sec = (s[0]*3600 + s[1]*60)

        for i in e:
            e_sec = (e[0]*3600 + e[1]*60)

        return (e_sec - s_sec)

    delta = round(td(self)/3600,1)

    if self.group.checkedId() == 1:
        self.date1 = self.EvereDate1.date().toPyDate()
        self.date2 = self.EveryDate2.date().toPyDate()
    elif self.group.checkedId == 2:
        self.date1 = self.WaWdate1.date().toPyDate()
        self.date2 = self.WaWdate2.date().toPyDate()
    else:
        self.date1 = self.OnceDate.date().toPyDate()
        self.date2 = "              "
    
    str_val = (str(self.date1)+"        "+str(self.date2)+"     "+self.timeStart.strftime("%H:%M")+"                "+self.timeEnd.strftime("%H:%M")+"          "+str(delta)+"                      "+paramTecher+"             "+paramSubj+"\n")
    file = open("test1.txt", "+a")
    file.write(str_val)
    file.close
    print(self.date1, self.date2, self.timeStart, self.timeEnd, delta, paramTecher, paramSubj)


def rbtn (self):
    if self.group.checkedId() == 1:
        self.EvereDate1.show()
        self.EveryDate2.show()
        self.WaWdate1.hide()
        self.WaWdate2.hide()
        self.OnceDate.hide()
    elif self.group.checkedId() == 2:
        self.EveryDate2.hide()
        self.EvereDate1.hide()
        self.WaWdate1.show()
        self.WaWdate2.show()
        self.OnceDate.hide()            
    elif self.group.checkedId() == 3:
        self.EveryDate2.hide()
        self.EvereDate1.hide()
        self.WaWdate1.hide()
        self.WaWdate2.hide()
        self.OnceDate.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the values ​​​​of the variables are not updated to the new ones"?

Comment: I am passing date values ​​to date1 & date2 variables. They should change depending on the selected radio button.

Comment: Change *where*? You set those *attributes* only in `Add`, not when you click the radio buttons, because `rbtn` only changes the visibility.